# Can you create your own task configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example. Lets say I am working on a project in Java and I want a task that will compile, and another task that will run. Here is what the builder would automatically create for me, and I can then configure:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "javac",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "taskName": "java",
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

And this default user created JSON would show up as another option when you are configuring your Task Runner:
[The default options for Task Runner configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L644.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking whether an extension can add a default config to the "configure task runner" menu in vscode? I don't believe so. I think those defaults are just built in examples. You could make a feature request on github, though.